# Update patchset

Tags: git, gerrit

On gerrithub (http://gerrithub.io/)
I committed patchset1 and want to update it to patchset2.

[procesdure]

1. git add test.cpp
2. git commit -m "commit -1"
3. git push https://username@review.gerrithub.io/username/testproject HEAD:refs/for/master

for patchset2

4. git add test.cpp
5. git commit --amend
6. same as 3.

but there was another new commit on gerrithub site.
How can i make patchset2?

Comment: The commnand is working like below. curl -Lo .git/hooks/commit-msg http:// review.gerrithub.io/tools/hooks/commit-msg

Answer (score 2):

If you want Gerrit to automatically correlate amended commits to the originally uploaded changes (i.e. create new patch sets when you upload a new version of a change), make sure your commits have the Change-Id commit message footer set. This is easily done with a commit-msg hook.

Another option is to push the amended commit to refs/changes/123, where 123 is the sequential change number that each change is assigned.

Relevant Gerrit documentation links:

- [Change-Id documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html)
- [*Reworking the change*](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html#_reworking_the_change) section from the documentation's [Quick Introduction](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html) page.
- [*Replace Changes*](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#push_replace) section from the documentation's [Uploading changes page](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html).